# How can we prove that $\gcd((n^4) + (n+1)^4 , (n+1)^4 + (n+2)^4) = 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

I have found through experimentation that the consecutive sums of consecutive natural numbers raised to certain powers$(1,2,4)$ are always coprime. I was looking for modular multiplicative inverses and came across this facet. 
If you define a sequence $a(n): n^k + (n+1)^k$ , then $a(n)$ and $a(n+1)$ are coprime when $k=1,2$ or $4$ but no others. How can we prove this?

Since $a(n)$ and $a(n+1)$ are coprime when $k=1,2$ or $4$, their modular multiplicative inverse exists, and are sequences in the OEIS already.

I sincerely hope that this is moderately worthy and not cringe.

Comment: Please use MathJax for better visibility. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial.

Comment: Noted, MathJax for everything now on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $d$ is a common factor of $n^4+(n+1)^4$ and $(n+1)^4+(n+2)^4$. Then
$$d\bigg|(n+2)^4-n^4\\
\implies d\bigg|4(n+1)(n^2+(n+2)^2)$$
But note that $4(n+1)$ and $d$ are coprime (since both of the given numbers are odd, hence $d$ is also odd, also, if $k$ is a common factor of $d$ and $n+1$, then $k$ also divides $n^4$ which is a contradiction, since, $k$ and $n$ are coprime). Hence,
$$d\bigg|n^2+(n+2)^2\tag1\\
\implies d\bigg|n^4+2(n+1)^4+(n+2)^4-\Big(n^2+(n+2)^2\Big)^2\\
\implies d\bigg|2(n+1)^4-2n^2(n+2)^2\\
\implies d\bigg|\Big((n+1)^2-n(n+2)\Big)\Big((n+1)^2+n(n+2)\Big)$$
$$\implies d\bigg|2n^2+4n+1\tag2$$
Subtracting the second equation from the first one, we get,
$$d\bigg|3\tag3$$
Hence, $d$ is either $1$ or $3$. Since exactly one of $n, n+1$ and $n+2$ is divisible by $3$, we are done.

**EDIT**

As N.S. pointed out in comments, after $(1)$, if one observes that
$$\Big(n^2+1\Big)\Big(n^2+(n+2)^2\Big)-\Big(n^4+(n+1)^4\Big)=3$$
then $d$ being a common factor of both terms in LHS, is also a factor of RHS and we again reach $(3)$.

Comment: This is incredibly slick logic. Very satisfying process. Thank you. It took me a second to process, but this exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @TheHoyt, you're welcome:)

Comment: Once you get to (1) you can simply note that $$n^4+(n+1)^4= \left(n^2+1 \right)(n^2+(n+2)^2) -3$$ and you are done.

Comment: $$\left(n^2+1 \right)(n^2+(n+2)^2)=n^4+n^2(n+2)^2+n^2+(n+2)^2=n^4+(n^2+2n)^2+n^2+(n+2)^2=n^4+(n^2+2n+1-1)^2+n^2+(n+2)^2=n^4+(n+1)^4-2(n+1)^2+1+n^2+(n+2)^2$$

Comment: Thank you, @N.S., included that in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Given $a(n)=(n+1)^4+n^4$.

You can check that:
$$(4 n^3 + 20 n^2 + 39 n + 29)\cdot a(n)  -  (4 n^3 + 4 n^2 + 7 n + 1)\cdot a(n+1) = 12$$

Therefore any common factor of $a(n)$ and $a(n+1)$ must divide $12$.

You can find this by using the extended euclidean gcd algorithm applied to polynomials. I confess I did not do that by hand, but used [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polynomial%20extended%20gcd%28%20%28n%2B1%29%5E4%2Bn%5E4%2C%20%28n%2B2%29%5E4%2B%28n%2B1%29%5E4%29).

So now you only need to prove that $2$ and $3$ can never be a common factor. It is easy to see that $a(n)$ is odd whether $n$ is odd or even, and also that it is never a multiple of 3 regardless of whether $n\equiv 0,1,2\mod {3}$.

Similarly if $a(n)=(n+1)^2+n^2$ then you have

$$(n+2) \cdot  a(n) - n\cdot a(n+1) = 2$$

so the only possible common factor could be 2, but this can be ruled out because $a(n)$ is always odd.

Comment: Thank you so much. The polynomial extended gcd is truly remarkable, especially for things like Pade. This is truly great insight. I must admit, I do not know how we can 'check' modulo 3 and 4 for a proof? I would like to truly understand.

Comment: I appreciate the edits. I now see the logic you employ. I wish I could make both answers be the answer.

Comment: @TheHoyt As is typical, it's much easier to use mod arithmetic than to compute the full-blown Bezout identity, e.g. I do it in a couple minutes of easy mental arithmetic in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A quick mental way: suppose prime $p\mid f_n=(n\!-\!1)^4+n^4$ and $\,p\mid f_{n+1}.\,$ Then

$\!\bmod p\!:\ (n\!-\!1)^4 \equiv -n^4 \equiv (n\!+\!1)^4$ $\Rightarrow\, 0 \equiv (n\!+\!1)^4-(n\!-\!1)^4 \equiv 8n(n^2\!+\!1)$

contra $\,p\nmid 2\,$ by $\,f_n\equiv \color{#c00}{\bf 1}\pmod{\!2},\ $ $ p\nmid n\,$  by $\,f_n\equiv \color{#c00}{\bf 1}\pmod{\!n},\,$  and $\,p\nmid n^2\!+\!1\,$ else $\,p^{\phantom{|^{|^|}}}\!\!\mid\, f_n\bmod n^2\!+\!1 = -3,\,$ so $\,p=3\mid n^2\!+\!1,\,$ contradiction.